# What can linking to a CMake target impact?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, linker, include-path

I ran into an interesting problem today. I am trying to compile and link a test executable to the Boost unit test framework and I tried it in two different ways.

1. The classic approach of linking directly to the "boost_unit_test_framework" library using `-lboost_unit_test_framework`
2. The modern CMake approach of linking to the `Boost::unit_test_framework` CMake target.

Interestingly when I link to the library directly my code compiles and links fine; however when I link to the CMake target my code fails to compile before it even gets to the linking stage!

The errors I get are related to a header file that it suddenly can't seem to find anymore. This suggests that linking to the `Boost::unit_test_framework` somehow messed with my include path.

I know linking to a CMake target is supposed to be the more modern and preferred approach, but if it can have such unexpected and unexplainable side effects, it seems worse than just linking straight to the library...

Why would linking the CMake target cause header files to not be found anymore? Also what other kinds of things can linking to a CMake target instead of linking directly to a library impact?

---

In both scenarios I am using `target_link_libraries` to link to the boost library. For example

```
target_link_libraries(mytest_exe
    testlib
    -lboost_unit_test_framework
)
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(mytest_exe
    testlib
    Boost::unit_test_framework
)
```

Comment: "my code fails to compile before it even gets to the linking stage" - Please post your *exact* compiler errors. As well as information on what compiler (and version) you are using. A [mcve] would be best.

Comment: your code can only fail to compile before linking, linking comes after compilation ;)

Comment: I cannot post the exact compiler errors for security reasons. I can, however state that it is missing things that are defined in one of the header files it uses. That should be all the info needed to answer the actual question of "What can linking to a CMake target impact?". I'm not asking why my specific example fails to compile. I'm asking what impact linking to a CMake target can have.

Comment: @user463035818 The fact that it is failing before linking means that the `target_link_libraries` command in CMake actually effects more than just linking. It is effecting the compilation as well. My question is why would `target_link_libraries` effect the compilation? It doesn't seem intuitive.

Comment: if you cannot post the exact messages of the original code you should prepare a [mcve], something that is not confidential and reprocudes the problem

Comment: @user463035818 There is no "problem" I am asking WHAT it can effect, not WHY

Comment: @nos It doesn't fail compilation until I change the contents of `target_link_libraries` meaning that `target_link_libraries` can in fact effect compilation. This was a surprise to me, so I am asking in what ways can it effect compilation?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 The fact thet you use the cmake "target_link_libraries " can be quite important, as opposed to lo normally linking to a libr,ary. Please update your question. If you also had shown us the line in your cmake files (and preferrably copy/pasted the error messages you got as well) that caused your particular issue, most of this discussion could be avoided

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Why is it a surprise.  It's documented behavior as part of [transitive usage requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements).

Comment: @Fred, that info looks like what I was looking for! Is there any way to list what transitive dependencies get pulled in? If I could see what it is pulling in I could likely pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The fact that it is failing before linking means that the `target_link_libraries` command in CMake actually effects more than just linking. It is effecting the compilation as well.

Yes, it is true that new include directories are added when you link with a library **target** instead of the library *file*. This is why the approach is called "modern" - a single `target_link_libraries` call does all things which are needed to use the library (Boost in your case).

Reason of failing with "modern" approach could be that "true" Boost headers **conflict** with other headers you use. You may detect that via inspecting chain of include files in the error message.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, oddly none of the errors mention any boost header files, and even printing the list of include paths before and after the call to `target_link_libraries` produces the same list of paths. At this point I'm still not sure what it modified, but I will keep looking in this direction.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure, but `unit_test_framework` could add not only include directories, but also **compile definitions**. (Linking with a target may modify almost any compiler option). Actually, you may compare compiler command lines in both cases to see a difference.

Comment: good idea! I'll run make VERBOSE=1 in both cases and diff the outputs to see what flags and compiler options might differ

Comment: Solved it! Sure enough it was modifying the include paths, it moved one of them to later in the list of include paths. That should not have been a problem, but some knucklehead decided it would be a good idea to put `include_directories(".")` in our main CMake script that all our code uses. This caused my current directory to be treated as a "system" directory. This meant that `#include <someheader.h>` looked in my own project for `someheader.h` and pulled that in when it should have only looked in the system header files for it...