# Why does external library adds compiler flag -std=gnuc++11 in cmake

Tags: c++11, cmake, c++17

I am trying to add external library VTK in my project using `cmake`. What I have noticed is when I try to add this external library it silently add `-std=gnu++11` but when I remove this third-party library that flag does not get added. Only flag I add is `-std=c++17`.

How I add external library is:

Tell cmake the place where I have installed vtk

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vtk)
```

.. now link with vtk library

```
TARGET_link_libraries(
   ${target}
   ${VTK_LIRARIES}
)
```

Comment: You should not set the C++ standard flag manually, use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` instead. Set it at the top level of the project and it should flow down gracefully and only be overwritten inside the thirdparty library

Comment: In between the code pieces you show you have `find_package(VTK)`, don't you? (Exactly this call sets variable `VTK_LIBRARIES`.) Actually, such call assignes library **targets** to the variable, and linking with such targets may change compile options. See also that my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260457/what-can-linking-to-a-cmake-target-impact/54260697#54260697

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes I do use find_package

Comment: I add set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) just after setting project and it works.

Comment: But I still had to do `add_compile_options` and add -std=c++17 in it.

Comment: @Rerito Is there alternate to set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) because it seems like it only available in cmake 3.8 and I have support cmake less then that.

Comment: Note that if you want to be sure cmake enforces it, you must also `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`